# is it possible to undo rake db rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollback, dbmigrate

I accidentally ran rake db:migrate, and then ran rake db:rollback. Now the database table I had created before is completely gone. Is there any way to undo a rollback, or should I just revert to the most recent branch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a `rake db:migrate` to perform the same migration once again.

Comment: After some search I realized that running rake db:migrate:redo STEP=1 solves my problem. Or just plain rake db:migrate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Just an update to existing answer by @sabaeus*

If `rake db:migrate` doesn't work for anyone, you can use `rake db:migrate:redo`.

`rake db:migrate` is to run all current migrations.